# Why does the alpha argument to stroke() cause nothing to be drawn?

Tags: java, processing

When I run the following code, my sketch draws as expected:

```
void draw() {
    int[] nextColor = getNextColor();
    stroke(nextColor[0], nextColor[1], nextColor[2]);
    float[] nextPoint = getNextLocation();
    point(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
}
```

However, if I add the fourth argument for the alpha transparency value to `stroke()`, nothing is drawn to the canvas at all:

```
float alpha = 0.8;
void draw() {
  int[] nextColor = getNextColor();
  stroke(nextColor[0], nextColor[1], nextColor[2], alpha);
  float[] nextPoint = getNextLocation();
  point(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
}
```

So far I have tried setting the alpha value to 1.0 directly in the argument (rather than using a variable) to be sure that I wasn't accidentally setting it to 0 somewhere. I have also double checked the [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/stroke_.html) for `stroke()` and there is indeed an overridden version matching my arguments.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is all of my code in case there is something elsewhere that should be considered. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;

Random generator;
int meanX, stdevX, meanY, stdevY;
int meanR, meanG, meanB, stdevR, stdevG, stdevB;
float alpha = 0.8;

// returns two random numbers (for x, y, coordinates)
float[] getNextLocation() {
  float[] retArr = new float[2];
  retArr[0] = (float) (generator.nextGaussian() * stdevX + meanX);
  retArr[1] = (float) (generator.nextGaussian() * stdevY + meanY);
  return retArr;
}

int[] getNextColor() {
  int[] retArr = new int[3];
  
  retArr[0] = (int) (generator.nextGaussian() * stdevR + meanR);
  retArr[1] = (int) (generator.nextGaussian() * stdevG + meanG);
  retArr[2] = (int) (generator.nextGaussian() * stdevB + meanB);
  
  return retArr;
}

void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(500, 500);
  generator = new Random();
  strokeWeight(10);
  
  // play around with these
  meanX = width/6;
  stdevX = width/8;
  meanY = height/2;
  stdevY = height/30;
  meanR = 224;
  stdevR = 20;
  meanG = 169;
  stdevG = 60;
  meanB = 20;
  stdevB = 5;
  
}

void draw() {
  int[] nextColor = getNextColor();
  stroke(nextColor[0], nextColor[1], nextColor[2]);
  float[] nextPoint = getNextLocation();
  point(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the value of `alpha` is.

Alpha means **transparency**.

Alpha values range from 0 to 255, with 0 being completely transparent (i.e., 0% opaque) and 255 completely opaque (i.e., 100% opaque).

So in your case, when you set your alpha to `0.8`, you don't see anything because it's very close to transparent. When you do not set the `alpha`, it is by default 100% opaque, so you see the drawing.

Take a look [here](https://processing.org/tutorials/color/) if interested to know more.

Comment: He's not misunderstanding what it is; rather he thinks Processing's alpha range (as it is generally) is 0...1, not 0...255.